# Could you easily switch from SoapClient to pear's Soap_Client

Tags: php, soap, pear

I recently changed hosts and found that they only support Pear's Soap_Client class and not the standard PHP SoapClient class and the opposite was said in the forums I looked through before making the switch. Is there a specific syntax that I could use to easily switch from one to the other? I'm not as familiar with the PEAR Soap_Client class to know the differences enough to make the conversion. So even a clear distinction between the two would be greatly appreciated. I've already got several classes/functions/methods running based off of this and it would be a pretty fair waste of money to have to switch hosts at this point. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is a small snippet of where I am calling the class:

```
        try {
        $soapClient = new SoapClient(
            $this->webserviceWsdl,
            array(
                'exceptions'    => 1,
                'trace'             => 1
            )
        );
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        return json_decode(json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'msg' => "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})")),1);
    }

    try {   
        $soapClient->__setLocation(str_replace(
            '%%foo%%',
            $this->responseConfig['foo'],
            $this->webserviceEndpoint
        ));
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        return json_decode(json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'msg' => "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})")),1);
    }

    try {
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($this->buildSoapHeader($function));  
        return $soapClient->__soapCall($function, array($params));
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        return json_decode(json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'msg' => "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})")),1);
    }
```

Comment: You should provide your current solution and ask help on it not just ask SO to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to solve anything. I was just asking if there was a known method or if someone who has a better grasp would know the differences enough so that I could understand and make the change. I generally do tend to add code whenever I do have a question, but I thought that this one was specific enough to not need it as it was purely a syntactical question. My code isn't so much broken as the new host just doesn't support the class. I just added the other bits to give an understanding of why I would want to do such a thing. If you want I can add a snippet.

Comment: I dunno the answe so I just upvoted your question hoping someone will answer

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to make your code use PEAR's SoapClient class instead of PHP's built-in class. Their APIs are too different.

That said, you should not use PEAR's SOAP client lib because it's unmaintained.

Try to convince the hoster to install the php-soap package on their server - that is not hard.

Comment: I figured that might've been the case, but was really hoping. I tried to convince them before, but it didn't go over so well. I will try again though. Thanks.